# Building adjacency matrix from faces array

Tags: matlab, graph-theory, mesh, adjacency-matrix

I am using this [code](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36316-local-depth-sift-and-scale-invariant-spin-image-local-features-for-3d-meshes) used in a toolbox for calculating adjacency matrix from a set of faces. My `faces` is an `m*3` array for example:

```
23  13  12
12  22  23
13  4   12
23  14  13
22  35  23
```

From  what I have understood, the adjacency matrix should be an `nxn` matrix where `n` is the number of vertices. For some of my mesh .ply files I get adjacency matrix which has a smaller dimension than the number of vertices. For example, `n=5047` but my adjacency matrix has dimensions `nxn= 4719x4719`.

What could be the reason for this behavior? I get this error not on all but some mesh files only.

The code:

```
function A = triangulation2adjacency(face,vertex)
% triangulation2adjacency - compute the adjacency matrix
%   of a given triangulation.
%
%   A = triangulation2adjacency(face);
% or for getting a weighted graph
%   A = triangulation2adjacency(face,vertex);
%
%   Copyright (c) 2005 Gabriel Peyr


[tmp,face] = check_face_vertex([],face);
f = double(face)';

A = sparse([f(:,1); f(:,1); f(:,2); f(:,2); f(:,3); f(:,3)], ...
       [f(:,2); f(:,3); f(:,1); f(:,3); f(:,1); f(:,2)], ...
       1.0);
% avoid double links
A = double(A>0);

return; 


nvert = max(max(face));
nface = size(face,1);
A = spalloc(nvert,nvert,3*nface);

for i=1:nface
    for k=1:3
        kk = mod(k,3)+1;
        if nargin<2
            A(face(i,k),face(i,kk)) = 1;
        else
            v = vertex(:,face(i,k))-vertex(:,face(i,kk));
            A(face(i,k),face(i,kk)) = sqrt( sum(v.^2) );    % euclidean distance
        end
    end
end 
% make sure that all edges are symmetric
A = max(A,A');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find a compact function [here](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5355-toolbox-graph?focused=5127601&tab=function) with name `triangulation2adjacency`. 
That graph toolbox is very useful for 3d mesh and graph functions.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem a while a go... in a difffent context but you migth still find my experience usefull:

My Problem was the misunderstanding that n≠No.Faces. n is the number of vertices and each face can have three or more. Some Faces share vertices and thats why n≠No.Faces.

In Your example try:

```
B=[23  13  12;...
  12  22  23;...
  13  4   12;...
  23  14  13;...
  22  35  23];

NoVert=numel(unique(B));
NoFace=size(B,2);
```

In an adjacency matrix each node/vertice gets a row/colum so for B this would be a Matrix of 7x7. 
Even bigger matrices result if the nodes are not numbered consecutively, for B this would result in a 35x35 Matrix, because the highest node number is 35.

---

a bit off topic, but try this :

```
G = digraph([B(:,1);B(:,2);B(:,3)],[B(:,2);B(:,3);B(:,1)]);
A = adjacency(G);
```

you will get the adjacency matrix with a lot less code. (and maybe time, did not test)

Comment: What I have given here is a small part of my actual faces array. In reality, faces= 3737x3 array. It is true that n is not equal to faces because no of vertices is, in this case, 5047. I mixed up the n in my question actually. Will edit it. Anyway I will try out what you said and see what I get. :) Thank you.